# Merging sets of columns with 0,1 and NA in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, tidyverse, multiple-columns

I have a tibble like this.

```
# A tibble: 45 x 10
   `q2-1` `q2-2` `q2-3` `q2-4` `q2-5` `q3-1` `q3-2` `q3-3` `q3-4` `q3-5`
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      0      1      0      1      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 2      0      0      0      1      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 3      0      0      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 4      NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     1      1      0      0      1
 5      0      0      0      1      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 6      0      1      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 7      0      0      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 8      NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     0      1      0      0      0
 9      0      0      0      1      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
10      0      0      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

I want to merge q2 and q3 while still keeping individual colomns.
(like q-1, q-2... q-5)
How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: You should specify the ""merging"" function. Do you want to sum the values rowwise? Or maybe get the max rowwise for every prefix "qx"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If you had offered `dput()` output wee would not have needed to redo the data entry.)

Appears you want missing values in the first 5 columns replaced by their corresponding values in cols 6-10 and the names of the columns changed to reflect that rearrangement. So use `is.na()` on the first five columns on both sides of a replacement for an index:

```
dat <- read.table(text="`q2-1` `q2-2` `q2-3` `q2-4` `q2-5` `q3-1` `q3-2` `q3-3` `q3-4` `q3-5`
     1      0      1      0      1      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 2      0      0      0      1      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 3      0      0      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 4      NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     1      1      0      0      1
 5      0      0      0      1      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 6      0      1      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 7      0      0      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 8      NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     0      1      0      0      0
 9      0      0      0      1      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 10      0      0      0      0      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA", head=T)
dat
   X.q2.1. X.q2.2. X.q2.3. X.q2.4. X.q2.5. X.q3.1. X.q3.2. X.q3.3. X.q3.4. X.q3.5.
1        0       1       0       1       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2        0       0       0       1       0      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3        0       0       0       0       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1       1       0       0       1
5        0       0       0       1       0      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6        0       1       0       0       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
7        0       0       0       0       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       0       1       0       0       0
9        0       0       0       1       0      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
10       0       0       0       0       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 dat1 <- dat[1:5]
 dat2<- dat[6:10]
 dat1[is.na(dat1)] <- dat2[is.na(dat1)]
```

The name stuff can be done with sub or gsub.

```
 names(dat1) <- gsub("X[.]","", names(dat1))
 names(dat1) <- gsub("^q\\d[.]","q-", names(dat1))
 dat1
#---------------------
   q-1. q-2. q-3. q-4. q-5.
1     0    1    0    1    1
2     0    0    0    1    0
3     0    0    0    0    1
4     1    1    0    0    1
5     0    0    0    1    0
6     0    1    0    0    1
7     0    0    0    0    1
8     0    1    0    0    0
9     0    0    0    1    0
10    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it worked! Also, sorry for the data, I'm new to here/programming in general. I will mind next time!

Comment: There a lot of good information and worked examples about how to deliver unambiguous data here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?r=SearchResults&s=1|1747.9037  In the pre-tibble era there was often ambiguity in the print output from the console, so we could never tell whether a column was a factor or character. Tibbles are unambiguous because they display their classes but they don't lend themselves to use as immediate text input. You need to strip out the class lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

  dat %>% mutate(map2_dfc(across(starts_with('q2')),
                         across(starts_with('q3')),
                         coalesce),
                .keep = 'unused') %>%
         rename_with(~str_remove_all(.x, "(?<=q)\\d+"))

  q.1 q.2 q.3 q.4 q.5
1    0   1   0   1   1
2    0   0   0   1   0
3    0   0   0   0   1
4    1   1   0   0   1
5    0   0   0   1   0
6    0   1   0   0   1
7    0   0   0   0   1
8    0   1   0   0   0
9    0   0   0   1   0
10   0   0   0   0   1
```

**data**

```
structure(list(q2.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L
), q2.2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L), q2.3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L), q2.4 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, NA, 
1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L), q2.5 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
NA, 0L, 1L), q3.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA), 
    q3.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), q3.3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA), q3.4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA), q3.5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

  q2.1 q2.2 q2.3 q2.4 q2.5 q3.1 q3.2 q3.3 q3.4 q3.5
1     0    1    0    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2     0    0    0    1    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3     0    0    0    0    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    1    0    0    1
5     0    0    0    1    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6     0    1    0    0    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
7     0    0    0    0    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
8    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1    0    0    0
9     0    0    0    1    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
10    0    0    0    0    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```